# Arch linux wifi broadcom | Not working

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, hardware, plasma

The output of `lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` is :

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Wifi is notwoking at all.

I am using lenovo E531, I am connected with external usb device and its woking fine.

What am i missing ?
Please help, I am having a hard time with this wifi.

Comment: you could take your chance with the alternate (proprietary) driver: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl . I read it doesn't work as well as the brcm80211, but it appears there's no firmware available even today to use the opensource driver.

Comment: @A.B Okay let me check that, I will let you know.

Comment: @A.B There are two variants, Which one should i use ? `broadcom-wl` or `broadcom-wl-dkms` ?

Comment: @A.B Okay, There is only stright installation right ? Or some confugrations too ?

Comment: Note I put a comment not an answer. I'm not even using Arch Linux. I was kind to put a pointer, that's it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install wifi driver in arch linux | Plasma KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438998/how-to-install-wifi-driver-in-arch-linux-plasma-kde)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. No rep to comment. You'd have to install the firmware (proprietary) first. Its in the 
[aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware-classic/).   A reverse engineered open source driver b43/b43legacy and open source drivers provided by Broadcom brcm80211 are already in the kernel. Install the firmware, remove other drivers (if loaded) and then load the driver according to your card. [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless)  already has defined it pretty nicely.

Another way which which @A.B suggested is that to install the proprietary driver.

I've done the former on debian and the process is a bit different. It provides a package to extract firmware b43-fwcutter. Install. Download firmware. Use it to extract. The rest of the process is the same.